# how to redraw google map with jQuery (Ruby on Rails 3)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

i have fields:

```
 <%= f.label :address %>
 <%= f.text_field :address %>
 <%= f.label :city %>
 <%= f.text_field :city %>
 <%= f.label :state %>
 <%= f.text_field :state %>
 <%= f.label :country %>
 <%= f.text_field :country %>
```

and script:

```
 $("#addr").focusout(function() { 
var param = $("#user_address").val();
 // code
 });
```

what code must be in function to redraw map with new address?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should check [geocoder](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#Geocoding_Object) or [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingRequests)